# If I have a process which is supposed to be receiving data from multicast, how can I check if it actually is?

Tags: linux, networking, multicast, debugging

I can check `gstack`, but just because I see the listener threads on the `recv` call does not mean that call is not returning. One other thing I thought was to do something like:

`netstat -lupe | grep <PROCESS_PID>`

to check the inodes of the sockets listening via udp. Then possibly try watching (`watch` command) what `/proc/net/udp` says about the receive and transmit queues of those inodes. I'm not sure if this is a good way to diagnose this, however. Trying to listen to the same multicast groups to check for data coming in is also not really a guarantee that the process in question is receiving it.

What are some other ways or things I could probe or try?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `netstat -gn` output to see joins.

`tcpdump` can help actually see activity... e.g: `tcpdump -i eth1 -s0 -net 224.0.31.0/24`